# with open() gives TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, typeerror, with-statement

Using pickle and trying to generate classifier result in python gives me a TypeError. I understand the general concept as to why this occurs but I am not sure what is wrong with my syntax. Everything runs until I get to this part.

Thank you in advance for your help on the syntax and any details you can give on what I am missing:

---

**in jupyter notebook cells:** .

```
# Preparing a trainig data set from our data

def prepare_training(models):
    dataset = open_dataset()
    validation_size = 0.50
    seed = 7
    X, Y = split_data(dataset)
    # --> split the data into two sets - one training, one test
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(
    X,
    Y,
    test_size=validation_size,
    random_state=seed
)
train_models(models, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)
```

---

```
# Using kfold to iterate through some models

def train_models(models, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test):
    classifiers = []
    # iterates through the models
    for name, model in models:
        # chooses the index's for test and training set
        kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=4)
        for traincv, testcv in kfold.split(X_train):
            # trains the models
            model.fit(X_train[traincv], Y_train[traincv])
            # tests the models, doesn't output the result
            model.predict(X_train[testcv])
        # final test on the original test set
        prediction = model.predict(X_test)
        print(name, accuracy_score(prediction, Y_test) * 100)
        with open(abspath,
            'pickle/' + name + '_classifier.pickle',
            'wb'
        ) as ph:
            pickle.dump(model, ph)
        classifiers.append((name, model))
    return classifiers
```

---

```
# Dictionary for Glass Types

glass_types = {
    '1.0': 'Building Windows Float Processed',
    '2.0': 'Building Windows Non Float Processed',
    '3.0': 'Vehicle Windows Float Processed',
    '4.0': 'Vehicle Windows Non Float Processed',
    '5.0': 'Containers',
    '6.0': 'Tableware',
    '7.0': 'Headlamps'
}
```

---

```
# Generating a short catalogue of classifers

classifiers = [
    'DecisionTreeClassifier',
    'SVM'
]
```

---

*all cells above run fine, but this cell outputs the TypeError*

```
# Checking for classifers -- if not in there, then it loops to create them

models = []

if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(abspath, 'pickle/SVM_classifier.pickle')):
#if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath('pickle/SVM_classifier.pickle')):#
for name in classifiers:
    with open(abspath, 'pickle/SVM_classifier.pickle', 'rb') as ph:
        models.append((name, pickle.load(ph)))
else:
    models.append(('DecisionTreeClassifier', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
    models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
    models = prepare_training(models)
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-eceaf68f7f00> in <module>
     12     models.append(('DecisionTreeClassifier', 
DecisionTreeClassifier()))
     13     models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
---> 14     models = prepare_training(models)

<ipython-input-49-fead6c6a1c89> in prepare_training(models)
     13         random_state=seed
     14     )
---> 15     train_models(models, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)

<ipython-input-50-a76ec7e93740> in train_models(models, X_train, 
Y_train, X_test, Y_test)
     17         with open(abspath,
     18             'pickle/' + name + '_classifier.pickle',
---> 19             'wb'
     20         ) as ph:
     21             pickle.dump(model, ph)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: you need to check [the docs for the open function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). You're passing in parameters either in the wrong way, or the wrong order. Based on this, you're trying to pass in the filepath where the filename should be, the filename where the mode should be, and the mode where `buffering` should be. Did you mean to concatenate the filepath instead of passing it in separately?

Comment: Use `os.path.join()` to combine directory path and filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
open(abspath, 'pickle/SVM_classifier.pickle', 'rb')
```

should be

```
open(os.path.join(abspath, 'pickle/SVM_classifier.pickle'), 'rb')
```